# Xdebug w/ PhpStorm highlights lines of code that are warnings/errors, but where is the actual message?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using PhpStorm with Xdebug to do remote debugging on a local server using WAMPServer.

When I enable remote debugging if there is a warning/error in the code I notice the debugger stops and highlights the line in blue. I am able to view all of the variables. However, I am not seeing the actual Warning / Error message. In VSCode it appears really big.

**There are two things I would like to achieve:**
1. See the messages of thrown errors.
2. Tell the debugger not to stop at warnings so I don't have to constantly hit the green continue button.

Comment: Did you look at the PHPStorm and/or XDEBUG configuration and/or their respective documentations

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, thoroughly to set it all up using Remote Debugging. I don't understand why phpstorm wouldn't throw the error message right in your face of the line of code it stops on.